# Horizontally scrolled mobile page won't limit to 100vh

Tags: html, css, overflow

I need the width of the whole website to be exceeding the viewport but not the height. I am using flexbox to align two divs that are each 100vw, so user horizontally scrolls. I have set the body to be 100vh height, as well as the parent container of the two divs (.tab-content) and I still have alot of height exceeding way beyond 100vh. I have checked and constricted all my elements to 100vh, but the whitespace is still there. I am testing on Firefox and Chrome and get the same result - on iPhone 7/8 view. This excess goes away only when I remove the second div (#about). Here is how the excess appears:
[image]

HTML:

```
    <body class="col">
       <div class="control">
          <p id="pause">&#9612; &#9612;</p>
          <p id="audio">♩</p>
       </div>

   <nav class="nav-container">
      <div class="mobile__header-controls">
         <div class="mobile__nav">
            <button class="mobile__more">+</button>
            <div class="mobile__process-nav">
               <a href="#show" data-tab-target="#show" class="mobile__tab">Show</a>
               <a href="#about" data-tab-target="#about" class="mobile__tab">About</a>
               <a href="#researchFilm" data-tab-target="#researchFilm" class="mobile__tab">Research Film</a>
               <a href="#stills" data-tab-target="#stills" class="mobile__tab">Stills</a>
               <a href="#lookbook" data-tab-target="#lookbook" class="mobile__tab">Lookbook</a>
            </div>
            <div class="mobile__main-nav">
               <a class="mabtn" style="text-decoration: underline;" href="/MA.html">MA</a>
               <a class="capbtn" href="/capsule.html">Capsule</a>
               <a class="babtn" href="/BA.html">BA</a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <a href="/index.html" class="info-back">Back</a>
      </div>
   </nav>
   <main>
      <div class="tab-content animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
         <div id="show" data-tab-content>
            <div class="video-wrapper">
               <video id="catwalk" playsinline autoplay loop preload="metadata">
                  <source src="/img/BA/Samson Leung Dear you, he said - CSM BA Fashion.mp4" type="video/mp4">
               </video>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="about">

         </div>
      </div>
   </main>
   <script defer src="/js/collections.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   max-height: -webkit-fill-available;
   text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
   box-sizing: border-box;

}

.col {
   overflow: hidden;
}

.col::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
}


.nav-container {
   position: fixed;
   margin: 0px;

}

.mobile__header-controls {
   display: block;
}

.mobile__header-controls a {
   font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   transition: all 1s;
}

.mobile__more {
   font-size: 3rem;
   margin: 2rem;
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.904)
}

.mobile__process-nav {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   height: 30vh;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.904);
   color: black;
   border: 2px solid black;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.mobile__process-nav.fade {
   opacity: 1;
}

.mobile__process-nav a {
   margin-left: 2rem;
   margin-right: 2rem;
}

.mobile__main-nav {

   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: flex-start;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   height: 20vh;
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: 5vw;
   margin-top: 35vh;
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mobile__main-nav a {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.904)
}
.info-back {
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: 80vw;
   margin-top: 50vh;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.904)
}

.tab-content {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   z-index: -10;
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
   overflow-x: visible;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   display: flex;
   /* flex: row nowrap;
   justify-content: flex-start; */

}

.control {
   position: absolute;
   height: 100px;
   left: 5vw;
   color: white;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-around;
   padding: 2rem;
   z-index: 200 !important;


}

#audio {
   font-size: 1.3rem;
   border: none;
   color: #ffffff;
   background: transparent;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: all 1s;
}

#pause {
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: all 1s;
}

#show {
   width:100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}
video-wrapper {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}

#catwalk {
   object-fit: cover;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;

}

#about {
   width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width:100%
}
```

JavaScript for dropdown + button:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-device-width: 850px)").matches) {
   morebtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      processMenu.classList.toggle('fade');
      let menuOpen = processMenu.classList.contains('fade');
      if (!menuOpen) {
         console.log(menuOpen)
         processMenu.style.pointerEvents = "none";
      } else {
         processMenu.style.pointerEvents = "all";
      }
   })

   // document.querySelector('.back-img').style.display = "none";

} else {}
```

Comment: Isn't the excess the `div#about`?

Comment: i needed the width of the whole website to be exceeding the viewport but not the height

Comment: do you still need help?

Comment: yess still can't figure out why it won't stay to 100vh